# RichTextBox throws exception when dragging and dropping inside it

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox and when I try to drag & drop inside it it throws exception:

[image]

it happens when I'm in debug mode and the ***common language runtime exception***
flag is on.

This is my XAML -

```
<Grid>
    <RichTextBox x:Name="rtb"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 IsReadOnly="True" />
</Grid>
```

this is code behind -

```
public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  rtb.AppendText("aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaabbb bbbbb bbbbb bbbb");
}
```

Comment: Do you have to have the CLR Exception flag set? I think MS uses the exception system internally to handle some cases that you usually don't have to worry about, and that's where the exception is occurring.

Comment: The exception you showed us has absolutely no link to a drag and drop, it's a click once exception. Also, the code behind you showed has no trace of a drag and drop towards any RichTextBox Control, however, as Rachel said, you should be okay without that flag set, this usually is to catch lower level unhandled exceptions.

Comment: Addendum to @Rachel's post, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677756/what-causes-an-invaliddeploymentexception-in-a-wpf-application) is same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set `AllowDrop = true` ?
If you haven't, you can get bizarre errors